# Code Igniter: Disallowed Key Characters in different browsers

Tags: codeigniter, uri, key

I've been developing my first app in codeigniter. It was all working fine last night but when I fired it up this morning I got the error 'Disallowed Key Characters', but then realized this error was only occuring in Firefox & not Safari (where the site loads fine)?

What issues do I need to look out for with 'Disallowed Key Characters', to make sure my app is compatible with all browsers (& cookie settings?).

Thanks!

--
Update- clearing cookies worked .:. allowed ci_session, although these were cookies for a different app (textpattern) on localhost (MAMP)- so again, what should I watch out for with cookies & code igniter?

Answer (score 0):

as you've identified, cookies can be a cause of this problem

without knowing more about the setup it's hard to be sure, but perhaps your cookies KEY contained an invalid character? I don't *believe* the value has any effect.

there's a few resources about showing what CI acceps and doesn't - it's pretty picky about invalid characters (such as `\n \r` as well as a host of others ) for security reasons

See [this thread](http://expressionengine.com/archived_forums/viewthread/58073/#286264) for a similar sounding problem